# Remove Norton One Icon?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons, norton-360

I recently installed Norton One, and it installed Norton 360. It works ok, but now I have a yellow "1" right next to my start button, on the taskbar!

How can I get rid of the icon while still keeping Norton 360, and Norton One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured it out.

In order to remove it, just right click on the Taskbar, select Toolbars, and untick "Norton Desktop Band".